# How i can load a CSS file in my wordpress theme head tag

Tags: css, wordpress

I am new to WordPress. I have a link and I want to add in **head tag of my WordPress** theme.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://pashtofonts.com/api/pashto.css" />
```

Please can someone help me in an easy way to add this CSS link into my WordPress theme.

I had seen other examples, but couldn't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to enqueue the script from inside your functions file.

Simply add the line below to the bottom of the `functions.php` file inside your theme directory.

```
function my_style_sheets() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'pashto-font-css', 'http://pashtofonts.com/api/pashto.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_style_sheets' );
```

This will ensure that your Pashto stylesheet gets loaded inside the HTML head of your webpage along with all of the other stylesheets your website makes use of.

Comment: thank u for helping me

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put css in ur head tag this will work fine.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://pashtofonts.com/api/pashto.css" />
```

But this is not a good practise. Write the following function in your functions.php

```
function resources(){

  wp_enqueue_style('pashto',http://pashtofonts.com/api/pashto.css',array());
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','resources');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to include you css file is paste the below mentioned line in header.php file of your wordpress theme and paste css file on the same